# Sympy Solve Taking forever to run

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy, solver

I've been trying to solve a system of equations with Sympy's `solve()` function; but whenever I run it in my Jupyter Notebook, the kernel just says it is busy and it doesn't seem to finish running and give me a solution.

This is what I was running:

```
from sympy import *

L = 2504 # mm
Ac = 3610 # mm^2
E = 203 # GPa
P = 587 # kN
theta = 42 # degrees

L = L*1e-3
Ac = Ac*1e-6
E = E*1e9
P = P*1e3
theta = rad(theta)

P1 = Matrix([0, -P, 0])
P2 = Matrix([-P, 0, 0])

ax, ay, cy = symbols('ax ay cy')

A = Matrix([ax, ay, 0])
C = Matrix([0, cy, 0])

eq1 = Eq(A + C + P1 + P2, zeros(3,1))
eq2 = Eq(L*cy + P*(L/2)*tan(theta) - P*(L/2), 0)

solve((eq1, eq2))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Not answer to your question, but I have two general questions for you. 1. You have 4 equations, but one is just zeros. Why? 2. Why use sympy for this rather than a numerical library like numpy or scipy?

Answer (score 2):

Which version of sympy are you using? With sympy `1.12.1` I get an immediate answer:

```
{ax: 587000.000000000, ay: 557768.587001416, cy: 29231.4129985840}
```

To find the version of sympy:

```py
import sympy as sp
print(sp.__version__)
```

Comment: I am using version 1.7.1. I am unable to upgrade sympy as I get the following

   'Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
    Requirement already satisfied: sympy in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.7.1)'

I believe this is because this is for a class where they give us a Jupyter Notebook and they restrict Sympy versions.

Sorry for the poor formatting, this is my first time using Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the old solver a simpler list of equations with less symbolics to check:

```
>>> solve(list(eq1.lhs-eq1.rhs)+[eq2.n()])
{ax: 587000.000000000, ay: 557768.587001416, cy: 29231.4129985839}
```